# Debugging constructor exceptions when using assembly.CreateInstance()

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I'm working on an app that creates a number of objects with a standard constructor by using `assembly.CreateInstance()` which all works as expected.

The complication however comes when the constructor raises an exception which is then raised in the calling code as a `TargetInvocationException` with the `InnerException` property set.
Is there a way to get Visual Studio to debug the exception as it does if I was calling the constructor directly?

I'm thinking of temporarily making it a switch block based on the type name, but this won't help when the objects are in a different (non referenced) assembly.

Sample code:

```
namespace CreateInstanceTest {
    public static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main() {
            Type testType = typeof(TestClass);
            TestClass test = (TestClass)testType.Assembly.CreateInstance(testType.FullName, false, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, new object[] { "value" }, null, null);
        }
    }

    public class TestClass {
        public TestClass(string param) {
            throw new Exception("My exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you write a quick app/test which calls the code directly, attached to a debugger?

Comment: This is still in the IDE anyway. If I add a breakpoint in the constructor (or code called form it), all goes ok until I hit the exception when it jumps back to the `CreateInstance()` call..

Comment: Yes, this exception is notorious with reflection and static constructors - but in the former case you have the benefit of being able to call the code directly and be able to debug it (if it isn't a static constructor issue coupled with using reflection.) In other words, if you called the constructor by means of `new MyType()`, you have a good chance of being able to step-through it.

Comment: That's pretty much the conclusion I'd come to, I was just hoping... :)

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox.

Comment: That does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging, I ended up using something similar to:

```
BuildAction action = null; //(BuildAction)actionType.Assembly.CreateInstance(actionType.FullName, true, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, new object[] { subReader, format }, null, null);
switch (actionType.Name) {
case "SetVariable":
    action = new Actions.SetVariable((XmlReader)subReader, format);
    break;
case "DisplayMessage":
    action = new Actions.DisplayMessage((XmlReader)subReader, format);
    break;
}
```

Which bypasses the dynamic `CreateInstance` call.